# Invalid syntax using regular expression in python 3.6.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

regular expression working in mac but giving error in linux. Linux has all python package but version is different

Mac python version =  3.7.9

linux python version = 3.6.8

```
line 99

    pattern = re.compile(rb"neighbor \d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+")
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can't reproduce in Python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Did you copy the code exactly into the question from the file you're trying to run on Linux?

Comment: Are you sure you're using 3.6.8, and not, say, 2.6.8? I could see this happening on 2.6.8, which doesn't have the `rb` string literal prefix, but not 3.6.8.

Comment: Python 2 gives exactly this error, indeed.

Comment: Can you make the code work with *any regular expression at all*? Also, did you check for unbalanced parentheses in the immediately previous code?

Comment: Thanks everyone. it have both python2 and python3 in linux. it was coming because of python2

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in existing comments, it seems likely you are using the wrong version of python

```
$ python2 -c 'rb""'
  File "<string>", line 1
    rb""
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$
```

```
$ python3 -c 'rb""'
$
```

What is the output of `python -V`, or if you are running this from some non-command line source

```
import sys; print(sys.version)
```

if you insert it on the line above your code?